# How can I possibly scrape the page that has no defined name and use a random class name on elements?

Tags: puppeteer

How can I possibly **scrape** the page that has no defined name and use a random class name on elements.

I basically replicate the HTML and just post some few content on it just for me to make it work using JavaScript which currently displays the output in console, but when I put it inside puppeteer it always gives me an error.

If you visit the page http://sx8army.com/test.html and inspect element you can see the product name and price of the product which I am planning on getting too hopefully including the  value value per product.

Thanks in advance.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    let url = 'http://www.sx8army.com/test.html';
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 10000});
    await page.setViewport({ width: 2195, height: 1093 });
    await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true, path: 'carousell.png' });
    const products = await page.evaluate(
        document.querySelectorAll('main').forEach(main => {
            main.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(product => {
                const product_details = product.querySelectorAll('p');
                const productName = product.textContent;
                const productHref = product.getAttribute('href');
                //console.log(product_details[0].textContent + " - "+ product_details[1].textContent);
                //console.log("["+productName + "] " + productHref);
            });
        })
    );
    await browser.close()

})()
```